# how can I authorize external access to my oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an *Oracle database* installed on my PC, it's *Express Edition*. I want to connect to this DB from another PC and I should grant an authorization for the used to be connected externally.
I know that on `Mysql` I can do this :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'%';
```

Before posting this question I looked on [oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#DBSEG99891) and I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
ALTER USER newuser IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;
```

How can I do the same thing on Oracle?

Comment: you grant everything to your mysql user so from this one cannot see  what you actually want. What is the meaning "connected externally". I assume that you want that the user gets the privilege to connect to the datatbase.

Comment: i want that my user can connect to my database from another machine, not only from localhost

Comment: That is not what "IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY" does.  That is used to create a user that is authenticated from a source other than the database, such as the OS or network.  There is nothing special you need to do to connect to Oracle over a network, other than having an oracle client and proper tns entries (among other options)